# Can I find out why a user got deleted?

Tags: support, status-declined, users

Very recently (a few hours ago), I got a reputation change of -22 reputation because a user (or more users) got removed. It seems I had edited 11 posts that just got deleted. 22 reputation isn't much, the world won't end, but I stand for it. I would want it back, but through the Help Center I found out that getting my reputation back is not possible.

I would like to know exactly why I lost reputation - that is, **why was the user removed**, or even better, **who got deleted**? Is this request accomplishable (either as an existing feature or possibly as a new one)?

Comment: Nope.  Users are deleted with a minimum of fanfare and maximum of privacy.

Answer (score 12):

@Frank is right. We don't release information on why a user was deleted, so you're just going to need to remain in the dark about it.

Comment: Yep, this. Anonymity of voting is a thing even if the user is no longer on the site.