# What happens to rep from upvotes and answer-accepts when a user is deleted?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

I answered a question today which pushed me to 200 Rep on the site (in turn auto pushed to 300 for the Association bonus). This user sometime later was deleted from the site, and I got some Rep removed (normal and I'm good with that. It was only 10).

My question is: will the Rep I gained from upvotes on my answer, along with the rep from answer acceptance be removed as well? And if so, how does that affect my Association Bonus?

This is the question in context: [What Version of Street Fighter 2 comes packaged in the SNES Mini?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/382538/264353)

---

As a side note, I do understand that I cannot find out why a user was deleted and that that is done on purpose ([Can I find out why a user got deleted?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11913/264353)) I have also read [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed) in which it explains the Site Policy. It didn't really help me out on figuring this out (unless I can't read....Wouldn't be the first time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a user is deleted, every single reputation change they've done to you via voting is reverted. This may case you to gain some or lose a lot of reputation. If you answered their question, you will still get *other people's votes as reputation, but if they themselves voted you lose that.* So on one answer/question you should pretty much only lose or gain up to one vote.

The reputation from the accepted answer will be kept.

---

Also, to answer the rest of the question, it isn't publicly shown why your profile got deleted for privacy.

Comment: Would the Rep from an accepted answer be taken? I know votes will, but the Accept itself be changed?

Comment: @Potterton how much reputation did you lose from him? If it ends in 5 then yes, if 0 then no

Comment: I lost 10 reputation.

Comment: @Potterton then no